# can I get a sentence using event.keyCode?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an easter egg for my website and I made javascript code. But it wasn't working for me.

I tried to trigger event.keyCode with typing c and output was working.(work) However, when I tried whole word(css), it wasn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onkeydown="function(event)">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>    
function function(event){
    var x = event.keyCode;
    if (x == 67) {
      alert ("work");
      if (x == 83) {
        alert ("work 2");
        if (x == 83) {
          alert ("boooom");
        }
      } else {
        alert("not working");
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from my code, I wanted to get "boooom" insted of not working. And I thought that I need a delay but I don't know how to put delay into script.

Comment: How can X be equal to  67 and 83 at the same time?

Comment: `function function(){}` is not allowed, also you are missing else ifs

Comment: Your event handler function will be called multiple times, once for every keydown event. You need to remember the last 5 letters, and only then compare whether they are what you expect.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have some typos in your code you should fix. Also, the use of `.keyCode` is discouraged as it has been deprecated. Instead you should use `.key`. You can find the direct answer to your question as a `switch` statement here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should name your function something other than **function** to prevent errors, second you need to keep track of keys pressed in the past, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onkeydown="keyPressed()">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var keys = '';  // Create list of keys

        function keyPressed(){
            keys += event.key;  // Add last pressed key to keys
            keys = keys.substr(-3);  // Set keys to the three newest keys
            if(keys === 'css'){  // If the last pressed keys are 'css'
                alert('boooom');  // Do easter egg
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: It might make more sense to put the onkeydown attribute in the **<body>** tag, since this is what's actually displayed. You could also extend this to allow for multiple easter eggs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onkeydown="keyPressed()">
    <script>
        var keys = '';  // Create list of keys

        function keyPressed(){
            keys += event.key;  // Add last pressed key to keys
            keys = keys.substr(-4);  // Set keys to the four newest keys (to free up memory)
            if(keys.substr(-4) === 'html'){  // If the last 4 pressed keys are 'html'
                alert('html');  // Do first easter egg
            }
            else if(keys.substr(-3) === 'css'){  // Else if the last 3 pressed keys are 'css'
                alert('css');  // Do second easter egg
            }
            else if(keys.substr(-2) === 'js'){  // Else if the last 2 pressed keys are 'js'
                alert('js');  // Do third easter egg
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you use **alert()** you will need to click on the page before entering one of these easter eggs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to track the history of the letters.

Each time the key is pressed add it to an array, then check to see if the last n letters are the ones you care about.

```js
var letters = [];

function cb(event){
  // push the new letter into the array
  letters.push(event.keyCode);
  
  // if there are 3 or more letters, check the last three
  if (letters.length > 2) {
    if (letters[letters.length - 1] === 83 &&
      letters[letters.length - 2] === 83 &&
      letters[letters.length - 3] === 67) {
      alert("boooom");
    }
  }
}
  
document.addEventListener('keydown', cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this one:

```
var lastKeys = [],
    triggerWord = "css";

function easteregg(event){
    var k = event.key;
    lastKeys.push(k);
    lastKeys = lastKeys.splice(-triggerWord.length);
    console.log(lastKeys)
    if(lastKeys.join("") == triggerWord) {
      console.log("bingo!");
    }
  }
```

Using `event.key` instead of keyCode will get you the actual character, which makes this easier to handle, assuming you don’t need to react to other stuff such as cursor keys, etc. Although those will create entries such as `ArrowUp` in the lastKeys array - that is unlikely to match the trigger word, but you might want to add some filtering for actual “characters” or something.

`lastKeys = lastKeys.splice(-triggerWord.length)` limits our array to the last x items that where pushed onto it (x = 3 for trigger word "css")

And then we just check if the concatenated contents of this array match the trigger word.

Maybe you want to add toLowerCase, so that typing some of the letter in upper case still results in a match.